# To extract the filename and modified date of list of files in a directory using R

Tags: r, file

I have list of files in Date format "YYYYMMDD". I need to extract files and modified date in such format so that filenames have to be taken of last 7 days. Suppose I have files named like "2014-08-12","2014-08-11","2014-08-10","2014-08-08" and "2014-08-01". Now out of these 5 files, I have to keep 4 files which is of last 7 days and its modified time.

I am using Code in R:

```
    library(tools)

y<-data.frame(FileName=basename(file_path_sans_ext(gsub(".*\\\\.*\\\\(.*)","\\1",dir()))),Modifiedtime=file.info(dir())$mtime)

i=1
z<-data.frame(a=y$FileName,b=y$Modifiedtime)

for (i in seq_len(nrow(z)))
{
  if(difftime(Sys.Date(), as.Date(y$FileName[i]), units = "days") <= 7)
    {

    dt<- cbind(z$a[i],z$b[i])  
    }
}
```

I am getting only 1 filename in dt. My problem is how to get other 3 filename.

Answer (score 1):

To select the four filenames, you could do:

```
fn <- c("2014-08-12","2014-08-11","2014-08-10","2014-08-08","2014-08-01")
(fn <- fn[difftime(Sys.Date(), fn, units = "days") <= 7])
# [1] "2014-08-12" "2014-08-11" "2014-08-10" "2014-08-08"
```

Comment: How to find modified time corresponding to only those files in a dataframe and thanks for your help.

Comment: To get the modified time for all .txt files in the current working directory, you could use `file.info(list.files(pattern=".txt"))$mtime`.

Comment: It will give modified time for all the 5 files....how to include only modified time for 4 files which are of last 7 days along with the file name

Comment: This will give the filenames for files which have been modified in the last 7 days:`fi <- file.info(list.files(pattern=".txt")); (fn <- row.names(fi)[difftime(Sys.time(), fi$mtime, units = "days") <= 7])`

Comment: If you want the filename + modified time, try this `dt <- difftime(Sys.time(), fi$mtime, units = "days") <= 7; setNames(fi$mtime[dt], row.names(fi)[dt])`